# Apache Spark ignores setting "spark.sql.warehouse.dir" when saving data with saveAsTable()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, delta-lake

I'm using Apache Spark with Delta lake feature. Spark runs as "Standalone" mode (`start-all.sh`). PySpark was started as followed:

```
pyspark --master spark://an_ip_address:7077 
        --packages io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.0.0 
        --conf "spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension" 
        --conf "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog"
```

Within PySpark shell, I load some data, and then save the DataFrame as followed:

```
x.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("ABC")
```

Of course, one then can query: `spark.sql("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ABC")` without problems.

#### Problem

However, checking the disk, there is a folder `spark-datawarehouse` created in `/home/ubuntu`. In this folder, we can clearly see folder `ABC` representing the table `ABC` (e.g. `_delta_log` child folder, *.parquet file). In contrast, on HDFS, there is also a folder name `ABC` but there is no data/file inside!

Said in other words, **it is supposed to save data on HDFS, not local disk with local path**.

One can query `spark.sql("DESCRIBE FORMATTED ABC")` and get:

```
+-------------------------------+------------
|col_name                       |data_type  
+-------------------------------+------------
...
|# Detailed Table Information   |                                                                |       |
|Name                           |default.ABC                                                 |       |
|Location                       |file:/home/ubuntu/spark-warehouse/ABC                       |       |
|Provider                       |delta                                                           |       |
|Owner                          |ubuntu                                                          |       |
|Table Properties               |[Type=MANAGED,delta.minReaderVersion=1,delta.minWriterVersion=2]|       |
```

#### Attempts to fix

I tried applying setting `spark.sql.warehouse.dir` in either of the 2 places:

- In PySpark starting, add: `--config spark.sql.warehouse.dir=hdfs://an_ip_address:9000/mydatawarehouse`.
- In file `spark-defaults.conf`:

```
...
# spark.driver.memory              5g
# spark.executor.extraJavaOptions  -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Dkey=value -Dnumbers="one two three"
spark.sql.warehouse.dir hdfs://an_ip_address:9000/mydatawarehouse
```

In both cases, in PySpark, I see the setting `spark.sql.warehouse.dir` is set correctly. Nevertheless, when saving with `saveAsTable("ABC")`, the above problem persists, no matter what.

#### Environment

- The machine hosting Apache Spark cluster: Ubuntu 22 LTS (x64).
- Apache Spark v3.2.2
- openjdk 11.0.16 2022-07-19
- Python3 3.10.4
- HDFS/Hadoop 3.3.4

Comment: If adding `.option("path", "hdfs://an_ip_address:9000/mydatawarehouse/ABC"` when saving, it saves correctly in HDFS as expected. However, the table properties, as in `DESCRIBE FORMATTED ABC` show `[Type=EXTERNAL,delta.minReaderVersion=1,delta.minWriterVersion=2,external=true]`.

Comment: maybe there is some other property which overwrite this location in deltalake. i think it's also because you are testing in standalone mode in local, if you are using hdfs cluster then no problem like this would be produced.

Comment: @Young Yes, I use Spark as Standalone cluster. But I still store data in HDFS and connect to the Standalone cluster with PySpark, using `--master spark://remote_host:7077`.

Comment: yep check out other property because spark does not have its own managed table, it only stores metadata in its catalog. i know little about delta lake, maybe it uses hive inside and that's the property which overwrite yours.